# Sharing Finds in No Man's Sky

Tags: steam, no-mans-sky

I have found some pretty crazy things in No Man's Sky and I would like to share the finds with my friends outside of the game.

Is there a way to do this other than taking screenshots and sharing them through Steam?

Comment: I'd imagine someone read the part about getting an API for the game to do some coding for it, which is kind of off topic here, even if it is for a game.

Comment: There's only one vote so far, but it's for the reason "Questions that ask for recommendations of games, servers, software, or hardware are off topic. For more information on why these sorts of questions don't work here, see "So, what actually is a Game-Rec?" and "Q&A Is Hard. Let's Go Shopping!""

Comment: We usually equate "Does software X exist?" questions with recommendation questions.

Comment: The question of "Is there an official, public API for getting information from the No Man's Sky universe?" is, IMHO, fairly on-topic. However, it comes with the potential problem of being time-localized (i.e.: if there isn't one now, the correct answer now may be rendered invalid in the future - or, if there is one now, the correct answer may later be rendered invalid if Hello Games decides to turn it off later). The real problem with your question though is the "Is there a website that does X" part. Absent an official website from Hello Games, that's asking for product recommendation.

Comment: I have amended the question to remove the request for API links and to specifically ask for links to an official site from either the developers or the publishers.

Comment: Asking for a site that meets specific criteria is still asking for a recommendation.  Whether it's official or not is immaterial; it's still a recommendation.  Rather than asking for a site, focus on the problem you think this information is going to solve.  Ask us that, and we might have a good question.

Comment: Perhaps it just needs a "How can I share my discoveries with my friends?"

Comment: How would you like to share it exactly? Outside of screenshots I'm not sure what else can be done here.

Comment: ah, maybe there's some kind of API or online database... (yay, full circle!)

Comment: Do you mean something like [gyazo](https://gyazo.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The most that is possible inside the game is the scan for nearby discoveries, and that usually only works when your friends are quite close by. Currently, Sean has said on his twitter [here](https://twitter.com/NoMansSky/status/763270760240713728?lang=en-gb) and [here](https://twitter.com/NoMansSky/status/763271005003538432?lang=en-gb) that multiplayer is included, but the servers are too overloaded to cope with it at the moment. This leads us to believe that it may be a while before "your friend showing up on the galactic map" is in the game. So that option isn't impossible, but highly unlikely at the time of writing.

Outside the game, Sean and Hello Games haven't made anything that links to the inside of the game, like an API, just yet. The community itself is working on some things, such as a list of all crowdsourced discoveries and more. However, apart from these and simple things such as recording and screenshots, there is no way to share your discoveries with friends.

Comment: I have accepted this answer until an official method is released.